# Is it possible to show the 'Login as member' link to non super admin groups?

Tags: members, accounts

Does anyone know if it's possible to show the 'Login as member' link, (available to super admins  on Member Profile view, under 'Member Administration') to other member groups??

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is not possible without hacking the EE core.

If you look at the `do_login_as_member()` function around line 590 of `system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/members.php` you will see:

```
    if ($this->session->userdata['group_id'] != 1)
    {
        show_error(lang('unauthorized_access'));
    }
```

ie, the access restriction of this function to superadmins is hardcoded into the core. You would need to either hack that file (and document it so that when you update EE you can reinstate it) or write an extension based on the code from that function.

Comment: Just changing this line won't work, you have to also find the form used to submit your admin password, etc. I haven't been able to find that code yet, though.

Comment: Correction, it's not the *form* I can't find, it's the code that allows the member group to *view* the form.

Comment: The form code is found in /system/expressionengine/views/members/login_as_member.php (which will call members.php->do_login_as_member())

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without hacking the core code. You could write an extension or something to do it most likely so you didn't have to hack the code, but bottom line is some code must be written.